# Unable to connect to existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, c, database, windows, mysql-connect

I have a database, I can see it with phpMyAdmin.
But when I try to connect in my C program it fail and mysql_error only return :

```
Unknown database 'database-name'
```

There is no spelling mistake so why doesn't it work ?

EDIT : here is the code used :

```
if(mysql_real_connect(&mysql, address, username, password, database, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", mysql_error(&mysql));
    exit(1);
}
```

address, username, password and database are char * with the correct values and it's not an issue with user's rights.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: please post some code which you tried so far...

Comment: What user do you use for the connection and has it been granted access to the said database from that host?

Comment: How did you initialize the `mysql` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on my own MySQL version, it worked, after re-installing MySQL on the destination computer it worked. Sorry for the disturbance.